# Int value changes when insert into mysql database - php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql with a field called "userId":

```
`userId` int(20) NOT NULL
```

Insert statement is:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (userId, firstName, lastName, dateCreated) VALUES (".$me['userId'].", '".$me['first_name']."', '".$me['last_name']."', CURDATE()) ")or die(mysql_error());
```

The value of userId when echoed in php is 100000517980247, but when inserted it changes to 2147483647. When I insert it into a varchar field it's fine. This has to be something really simple but I searched around a bit and I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MySQL ints are a signed 32bit integer. You're inserting a number that's far above the limit, so you're seeing the maximum possible integer, which is 2147483647.

Change the data type to bigint for a 64bit data type, which will handle your number.

Comment: thanks! Seems like an exception would be more useful in this case, rather than just inserting an acceptable value.

Comment: You can turn on strict mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_all_tables), which'd make MySQL reject any out-of-bounds values. Otherwise it'll silently coerce the value to fit into the field

Answer (score 2):

You use the type INT. And you need to use type BIGINT.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html