# MySQL changes numbers on insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem. My MySQL DB automatically changes numbers that I have entered. For example my command goes

```
INSERT INTO `some_table` VALUES (`66477096289`)
```

and MySQL saves it as `2147483647`

Field is `int(16)`. I've tried to update it using phpMyAdmin, I got same result...

Comment: Don't use backticks (`) for quoting literal values: you should only use backticks for table and/or column names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value as a `bigint` or `decimal` rather than a regular integer.

The number you are trying to save is 66,477,096,289.   It is larger than the maximum signed or unsigned int.

Comment: Works :) changed field to BIGINT

Answer (score 0):

That is called overflow. You are trying to insert a bigger number than the column can hold. Try using a larger int type (i.e. bigint)

Answer (score 0):

The type `INT` can only hold numbers up to 24147483647. As you are trying to insert a greater value, MySQL uses this maximum number instead.

If you want to store that number, use a bigger type, e.g. `BIGINT`. See also [MySQL Reference: Integer Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL ints are a signed 32bit integer. You're inserting a number that's far above the limit, so you're seeing the maximum possible integer, which is 2147483647.

Changed the data type to "bigint" for a 64bit data type, which'll handle your number.

[Int value changes when insert into mysql database - php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611600/int-value-changes-when-insert-into-mysql-database-php)

Answer (score 0):

**Use bigint, you are storing a large number which is exceeding the range**